# finding if all commits in Master are in release branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to compare with master branch before deployment. The process is as below.

1. Jira ticket created along with a new branch from master.
2. Change configuration in the repository and commit the changes to the branch.
3. Build and deploy.
4. On successful deployment merge the branch with Master and delete the branch.

The above process is continuously happening for at least 10 times a day since we get average of 10 tickets.
Bbefore build we will "git pull origin\maste" to ensure the deployed changes by someone else reflects in our deployment. Problem is sometime we miss to do it and the previous deployed changes will be overwritten or removed.

To avoid that we want to do a git pull master but we do not want to pull the changes without knowing what got changed. So we want to add a script in the pipeline which should see if master is having changes and branch is missing it, if missing then script should exit the build stage.

Tried below. Kindly help.

```
git log --oneline release_branch_test_case origin/master | wc -l
git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master release_branch_test_case
git status -sb
git pull origin master --dry-run | wc -l
git fetch;git diff | wc -l
git cherry master | wc -l

[ "$(git pull origin/master --dry-run | wc -l)" != "0" ] && (
echo "there are updates in master, do a pull" 
exit
)
```

The above script is what i want to do but its not working as expected.

Comment: "Problem is sometime we miss to do it and the previous deployed changes will be overwritten or removed." This is *not* typical, version control tools are specifically designed to handle this better than blind overwrites. A merge does *not* remove previous commits. You'd have to describe that part more for us to understand what's the underlying problem.

Comment: Actually when 2 person works on 2 different changes at same time one person will deploy first and the then he merges to Master so when second person deploys he has  to so git pull origin master to get changes done by the first person. If he miss to do the pull then the first deployment changes will be gone. to avoid that situation we want to put a script which should check if the deploying branch is ahead from master, if not build should fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Git's [two dot notation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) to determine whether a branch has commits that another one doesn't:

> This basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable from one commit but aren’t reachable from another.

For example:

```sh
git log master..feature
```

Returns the commits that are *reachable* from `feature` but *not* from `master`.

In your case, you can use [`rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list) with the [`--count`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---count) parameter to get the number of commits that are *reachable* from `origin/master` but *not* from your current release branch.

```sh
git rev-list --count release_branch_test_case..origin/master
```

Here's an example of a script that would do that for you:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# You can omit this if you're running the script as part of the build process,
# since the repo would have been freshly cloned by this stage
git fetch

# I'm using 'HEAD' here because I'm assuming that the script
# is being run while on the release branch
count=$(git rev-list --count HEAD..origin/master)

if [ "$count" -gt "0" ]; then
    echo "The master branch has $count commits that the current branch is missing"
    exit -1
fi

exit 0
```